# Angular: How to deal with shared data between components

Tags: angular, ngrx

For example, I have an account information that contains balance field (I fetch it from the server):

```
export class Account {
  constructor(
    // ...
    public balance: number  
  ) {
  }
}
```

I also have two components in which I need this field. Actually, the question is: how can I retrieve this account in my components?
I have a few assumptions:

**#1**
Fetch an account information in each component:

```
// First Component
this.accountService.get().subscribe(...);
// Second Component
this.accountService.get().subscribe(...);
```

This is the worst solution since I send two requests to the server.

**#2**
Fetch an account information in the AppComponent and then pass it to the children as inputs.
This is closer to the truth, but how can I pass this data to the router outlet?

```
<!-- Is this even possible? -->
<router-outlet [account]="account"></router-outlet>
```

**#3**
Use NgRx. Perhaps the best solution. The problem is that I don't need NgRx for other manipulations (In my case, it creates more problems than it solves), so I don't want to download such a big library and store it in my bundle.

---

So, should I consider using NgRx or you can advise me better approach for this problem?

P.S. I also have WebSockets that send me a new balance. I have to manage this as well. This looks like this:

```
this.socket.fromEvent('new_balance').subscribe(...);
```

Comment: Search how to share information through a service. Basic idea is to inject a service into the components and request that info to the injected service.

Comment: @dcg, and store fetched account in a service? I also have to manage WebSockets events. Should I also do it there?

Comment: If those events should impact/notify your components I think you can put that logic there too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please don't go for NgRx just for this. It's one of the most common mistakes people do. There are 'Angular' ways on how to deal with it.

**#1**

If you have a child - parent connection between your components. You can communicate in between them using [@Input / @Output](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction) decorators.

```
export class AccountChild {
  @Input() balance: number;
}
```

And then in parent component (component where you are calling AccountChild) you pass the balance like this:

```
<acconut-child [balance]="balance"></account-child>
```

**#2**

Another option would be to create a Subject out of your API response, and then you can subscribe to it from any other component.

```
export class AccountService {
  public accounts: Subject<any> = new Subject();

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient
  ) { }

  fetchAccounts() {
    return this.http.get(...).pipe(
      map((result) => {
         this.accounts.next(result);
      }));
  }

}
```

In order to call the API and load the subject with data you do this:

```
this.accountService.fetchAccounts().subscribe();
```

And now subscribe to that subject from component where you need that info.

```
this.accountService.accounts.subscribe((res) => console.log(res));
```

If you go for a way with subject and subscription it is important to unsubscribe manually from it when you are no longer using that component.

```
ngOnDestroy() {
  this.accountService.accounts.unsubscribe();
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Now I understand how can I communicate between components. One question left: where should I manage my WebSockets events? Because I have to alter balance field in the accounts subject when event comes.

Comment: @Feeco Normally these are also managed in services. You could create one service just for that (sockets.service.ts).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need ngrx to get the state management benefits of it... ngrx has a simple philosophy... you subscribe to state changes and take actions that update that state. data has one way in to state and one way out. so just apply that principle:

```
export class AccountService {
   private balanceStore = new Subject(); // state store
   balance$ = this.balanceStore.asObservable(); // state observable

   loadBalance() { // state altering action
     this.get().subscribe(this.balanceStore);
   }
}
```

now ngrx has a ton of tools to help you manage this state and all that, but this pattern works no matter what.

you may want to put the state loading action in a tap operator and return the observable to control the actual subscription in practice or use a BehaviorSubject and use things like a resolver, but the principles here are more or less universal.